# Jquery Accordion create function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

```
$("div.accordion").accordion({
                autoHeight: false,
                collapsible: true,
                active: false,
                icons: false,
                heightStyle: "content",
                create: function(event, ui) {
                    if($.trim($( ui.newPanel ).html()).length == 0){
                     $(ui.newHeader).find('span').removeClass('glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-plus').removeClass('glyphicon-minus').addClass('glyphicon-none');
                    }
                }
});
```

I'm trying to implement this create function on the jquery accordion, but it doesn't seem to be firing off when the accordion is created.

If I put this code into a beforeActivate event, it fires just fine.

How can I get this if statement to fire off when the accordion is created?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct. So, the only logical explanation is that your `if` check is not evaluating to `true`. To make sure, add this code and see if it fires anything into your console.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.accordion").on( "accordioncreate", function(){
    console.log('YES! It is working just fine.');
  });
});
```

Comment: Very good point here @Uzbekjon. The console does indeed log it. I think my issue is somewhere with the ui.newPanel. The create function doesn't use ui.newPanel, but I'm afraid I don't know exactly what it uses.

Comment: `ui` has only `header` and `panel`. Just look into the [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-create).

Comment: How is it possible to iterate through the panels if they are closed and will be empty objects? I need to check to see if they are empty and change the class of the header based on the result.